# Undefied index displying all of a sudden

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am getting an error message was has never happened before, i am using same code but i hae updated my xampp
Heres the code

```
<?php
session_start();
// Get the variable 

$op = $_REQUEST['op'];
$content = $_REQUEST['content'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$status = $_REQUEST['status'];


// Choose the operation
switch ($op){
    case "getList":
            $dbObj = new DBAccess();
            $dbObj->getList();
            break;
    case "addList":
            $dbObj = new DBAccess();
            $dbObj->addList($content);
            break;
    case "updateList":
            $dbObj = new DBAccess();
            $dbObj->updateList($id, $content);
            break;
    case "removeList":
            $dbObj = new DBAccess();
            $dbObj->removeList($id);
            break;
    case "removeAllList":
            $dbObj = new DBAccess();
            $dbObj->removeAllList();
    break;
}
```

I am getting the error for the op, content, id and status, but this has always worked before. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: how you r submitting the data? code please

Comment: undefined index on all my varbiables but when i insert if(isset($_POST[....) for them the error still occurs

Comment: You must be sending a GET request then, try `if(isset($_GET[....)` or `if(isset($_REQUEST[....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May Be Your error_reporting was off before update .. 
You can ignore this error by following code but still you gotta find where is for it happend

```
$op = isset($_REQUEST['op'])?$_REQUEST['op']:'getList';
$content = isset($_REQUEST['content'])?$_REQUEST['content']:'';
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:'';
$status = isset($_REQUEST['status'])?$_REQUEST['status']:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that no form has submitted (post), or no parameters have been passed through the url(get). If you want to get variables from the session, you should use `$_SESSION['op']` for example. `$_REQUEST` is considered bad practice since it contains all `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` data.